# Different definitions of a relatively compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $T,K$ be unbounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$.
I've seen the following definition of a relatively compact operator:

> (i) The operator $K$ is called *relatively compact* with respect to $T$, if for some $z$ in the resolvent set of $T$, $KR_T(z)$ is compact, where $R_T(z):=(T-z)^{-1}.$

I've also seen:

> (ii) The operator $K$ is called *relatively compact* with respect to $T$, if for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq H$ such that $(Tx_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, $(Kx_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Do definitions (i) and (ii) have something to do with each other, or are they distinct? *What is the intuition behind these definitions?* Definition (ii) looks like a generalisation of a compact operator, but definition (i) is just weird.

This question has also been posted on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336296/different-definitions-of-a-relatively-compact-operator).

Comment: What's $KR_T(z)$?

Comment: @mathworker21 For unbounded operators $T,W$ define a new unbounded operator $TW$ with domain $TD(W)$, where $D(W)$ is the domain of $W$, by setting $(TW)x:=T(W(x))$.

Comment: oh ok. I thought for some reason it was a set you were calling compact, which confused me. thanks for clarifying, though I think the domain of TW is $D(W) \cap W^{-1}[D(T)\cap range(W)]$, not $T(D(W))$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, you're totally right.

Comment: I think I can show (ii) implies (i) if $T$ is bounded (I know you said unbounded, but I'll take what I can get). Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence in $H$. Then $(T-zI)^{-1}(x_n) = -z^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{-j}T^j x_n$. Since $T$ is a bounded operator, $(T(T^jx_n))_n = (T^{j+1}x_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence, so (ii) implies $(K(T^j x_n))_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Taking a convergent subsequence for each $j$ (via a Cantor diagonalization argument), we see that $(KR_T(z)(x_n))_n = (K(-z^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{-j}T^j x_n))_n = (-z^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{-j}K(T^jx_n))_n$...

Comment: has a convergent subsequence, meaning that $KR_T(z)$ is a compact operator.

Comment: any thoughts on my above comments?

Comment: @mathworker21 Very nice, maybe it is possible to show $(i)=>(ii)$ in a similar way (at least in the bounded case). It is possible that they are equivalent for bounded operators and (i) is a generalisation for the unbounded case. I guess one has to look at some unbounded examples that fulfill definition (ii)

Comment: Also this is in the context of self-adjoint operators, so maybe the proof $(ii)=>(i)$ can be extended to the unbounded case by assuming $H$ is self.adjoint and using the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both definitions aim to make the same statement -- the operator $KT^{-1}$ is compact. But we cannot really to do that, because $T^{-1}$ does not necessarily exist, so in (i) we replace the inverse by the resolvent and in (ii) we write the more usual definition of compactness; if $(Tx_n)$ is bounded then $KT^{-1}(Tx_n)= Kx_n$ should contain a convergent subsequence.

Actually, (i) is equivalent to a version of (ii), where we only allow bounded sequences $(x_n)$. Indeed, to see that (ii) implies (i), pick a bounded sequence $(y_n)$. Then the sequence $x_n:= (T-z)^{-1}y_n$ is bounded as well, and $Tx_n= (T-z)x_n + zx_n = y_n + zx_n$ is bounded. By (ii), $(Kx_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence, but $Kx_n = K(T-z)^{-1}y_n$, so we showed compactness of $K(T-z)^{-1}$.

For the other direction, note that if the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(Tx_n)$ are bounded, then $((T-z)x_n)$ is bounded as well, so by (i) $K(T-z)^{-1} (T-z)x_n = Kx_n$ contains a convergent subsequence.

As stated in your question, the definitions are not equivalent (but (ii) still implies (i)). Note that (i) does not imply (ii), because any compact operator satisfies (i), but not necessarily (ii) (look at $T=0$).

Answer cross-posted from [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336296/different-definitions-of-a-relatively-compact-operator).